# How to insert variable in get date expression?

Tags: bash, date, variable

I've given a variable which hold a number

```
daysAgo=1
```

I would like to expand this variable in a get date expression. Like this:

```
$(date +%d -d '$daysAgo days ago')
```

What do I need to do that the $daysAgo variable gets expanded?

I tried like that without success:

```
daysAgo=1
exp="'${daysAgo} days ago'"
$(date +%d -d $exp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **"**, not **'**. Double quotes allows expansion of variables within the quotes, single quotes don’t.

```
daysAgo=1
echo $(date +%d -d "$daysAgo day ago")
06

daysAgo=1
exp="$daysAgo days ago"
echo $(date +%d -d "$exp")
06
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"` instead of `'`. From `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes.